# How can I password-protect a Mac shared folder on a Windows workgroup?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, passwords, network-shares, workgroup

We have a Mac-mini running `10.5.8` which already acts as a fileserver for our simple Windows (mixed XP/Vista) workgroup. The Mac-mini is on the same workgroup and the files are shared via SMB, FTP, and AFP. Basic file-sharing is **working**, and has been for some time.

We'd now like to add an **additional** directory/share which can be **secured by a password** so that only a small number on the network have access. Is this possible?

I've already tried creating the additional folder on the mac system, adding it to the shared folders, and limiting it to a specific "shared user", however it's not possible to log-in from an XP machine.

Adding a sub-directory to the currently working share and giving limiting it's access to the shared user doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

here's a little tutorial: http://lifehacker.com/247541/how-to-access-a-macs-files-on-your-pc

are you on the same workgroup? is it shared through SMB?

Comment: Yes, on the same workgroup. 10.5.8 doesn't have a "windows sharing" option, just "file sharing" which is set-up - we're just unable to secure a directory with a password.

Comment: i know it doesn't have the windows sharing option....this is addressed in a comment on the tutorial page